# How to reverse a 240 single phase 7.5 hp motor

Tags: motor, volts

Trying to use a WEG 240 Volt electric motor from a IR compressor to power a different compressor pump. The electric motor is wired for CW rotation and I need CCW. The motor has 2 Start Capacitors in series and 1 Run Capacitor. Looking inside the motor there are 4 wires coming off the windings but I am not sure if its possible to reverse the rotation. Can't figure out how to change the polarity on Starting Winding.

Thank You[image]

Comment: draw  diagram whowing what connects to where, include include a photo of the the motor name plate if present.

Answer (score 1):

If there are four wires coming from the motor windings not including the switch that disconnects the starting capacitor, you just need to swap two that are connected to opposite ends of the same set winding.

If the switch is in the interior of the motor with the windings, then two of the four wires connect the start and rum capacitors to opposite sides of the switch and the two windings have a common connection point that is not accessible. In that case, the motor can not be reversed.

Since the motor has a terminal block with moveable links but only the two power wires and two motor wires, I suspect the motor is not reversible. Reversible motors with that type of terminal block usually have all of the necessary wires connected to the block and a diagram in or on the motor showing how to position the links for each direction.

It is possible the the motor has two identical windings. In that case, it could safely be reversed simply changing which of the two windings is connected to the capacitors. However, if that is the case, that would be indicated on the motor nameplate. If the windings are not identical and you change the connection, the motor will reverse, but is likely tt be damaged before long.